# Executing MIPS binaries on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, mips

I have a 32-bit MIPS binary and I'm trying to execute it on Ubuntu 64-bit.

file command for the binary shows:

```
bin: ELF 32-bit MSB  executable, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
```

If I use qemu-mips to execute it, I get the following error:

```
/lib/ld-musl-mips-sf.so.1: No such file or directory
```

How can I execute it? I'd like to remote debug it using IDA Pro.

Comment: This is a dynamically linked binary. You need the corresponding libc package (like from [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/en/xenial/gcc-mipsel-linux-gnu) )

Comment: and then run `qemu-mipsel -L /usr/mipsel-linux-gnu/ ./filename`

Comment: Alternatively you can use qemu full system emulation and run the binary within [this](https://people.debian.org/~aurel32/qemu/mipsel/)

Comment: For debugging, run qemu-mipsel with the gdb stub (The -g parameter) and attach IDA to it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about running an executable, not reverse engineering. Per the subject, it might be on topic for [Ask Ubuntu](https://www.askubuntu.com).

Comment: @0xec I installed gcc-mips-linux-gnu, however, the required library cannot be found. Please note that the library this binary is looking for is: "ld-musl-mips-sf.so.1". It's the musl variant and I can't find that binary.

Comment: In that case check out the precompiled toolchains from https://toolchains.bootlin.com

Comment: Check out aboriginal http://landley.net/aboriginal/about.html or its successor, mkroot https://github.com/landley/mkroot.